Problema error con chrome al intentar lanzar codigo
estoy intentando lanzar un codigo en HTML y me sale un error  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, puede ser por un proxy o es algo del codigo en si?
Muchas gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si a todo...

Hola Owen, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Sin código no podemos responder nada, pero el error es super claro, NOT FOUND es literalmente NO ENCONTRADO. Eso ya dice mucho
